# How can I tell what is using a large VHD?

Tags: azure

I am running a VM in Windows Azure. It has two disks attached to it (OS 40GB and DATA 60GB).

In addition to my two VHDs, the Storage has one more 40GB VHD named dmzvyyq2.jja20130312104458.vhd.

I would like to know where this VHD came from and what is using it. Surprisingly the 'LAST MODIFIED' date is yesterday so something must have updated it. I went through all options in the Portal but nothing seems to have this VHD attached.

Ultimately I would like to delete this VHD to save storage space and cost.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to find out this is by using [`Storage Analytics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343270.aspx). If you have storage analytics enabled, you can view the contents of `$logs` blob container, download data for the data in question and check for all the activity on this particular blob. You can use a tool like [`Azure Management Studio`](http://www.cerebrata.com) from Cerebrata to view storage analytics data. However if you haven't enabled analytics on your storage account, it would be very tough to find out that information.